# Running QEMU with no gui but with VGA support

Tags: qemu, bare-metal, vga

I have a minimal bare metal application that utilizes VGA buffer to display text on the screen, and I want to be able to run in my terminal.

I've tried the `-nographic` option but it disables VGA entirely, leaving the serial port the only way (AFAIK) to display

I have tried running it normally and it works, but in a separated SDL window:

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=path/to/application
```

I have also tried running it with the `--nographic`, and it is how I want it to be (in the terminal and output is redirected to stdout):

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=path/to/application -nographic
```

And finally, I have tried running it with the `-display curses` option, which is the best variation I've managed to get, but it's not what I want, it still looks like a separate application and not something that runs in my terminal:

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=path/to/application -display curses
```

What I want is that the output from QEMU will be redirected to stdout, and to have VGA support.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `--display none`? You can also target SPICE or VNC if you want to access the display via another app.